# Finished texture painting and reopened blender and now it only shows as black. How do I fix this?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

After texture painting a mesh, I reopened blender, and I can see the material fully done in the paint slot, but it only shows as black now when selected. Unsure how to fix this.